Asian Movie involving a scene with a murderer and a child coming face to face on the side of a road
I never saw the movie but I was watching a show recently that was reviewing some Asian movies. All I can remember is that there was a scene where the Antagonist comes face to face with another character (possibly a child but I'm not 100% sure about it) at the end. I think the character knows they are face to face with the antagonist but says nothing.
I know the description is not helpful but its all I can remember from the review.
The movie is between 1998 and 2011. Its possibly Korean. It may be quite popular as some of the other movies that were reviewed included oldboy and battle royale.
Does anyone have an idea what it is? 

I found it. The movie is Memories of Murder (2003). Its a South Korean film.
I got the scene I described in the Question a bit muddled up. I found the description of the scene on wikipedia. The description below is a major spoiler so beware.

 Visiting the crime scene years later in 2003, Park Doo-man, now a businessman, learns from a little girl that the scene had recently been visited by another, unknown man with a 'plain' face. The little girl had asked him why that man was looking at a drain (from the scene of the second murder, which is shown at the start of the film), and he told her that he was reminiscing about something he did there a long time ago.

The film looks very interesting so should be well worth a watch.
